# MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle for large size database, calculation, depth analysis, and graph?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, oracle

I just come to use database management system and have no experience with all the DBMS programme. For those expert who have experience all the three platform, your opinion on this is very much appreciated. Please guide and let me know the pros and cons.

I been doing my database in Excel and would like to continue in other platform despite of the size of my folder is going bigger and handling the calculation, analysis and graph is getting slower and slower.

Comment: Most probably there will be no "right" or "wrong" answer. To give you a more detailed judgment we could use some information about the overall context (company, existing databases etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may not need to make the jump from Excel to the Mysql/SQL Server/Oracle level.

One prime consideration is, will you have multiple users/sessions using the data at one time. If not, the whole concurrency/locking layers of these databases are unnecessary overhead and you should look into something like SQLite.

Another is backup/recovery. Are happy happy to have 'snapshots' of your data (eg hourly/daily/weekly) and revert back to them if you have a problem, or do you need to be able to restore every last change even if you've been physically beating the flames out on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any DBMS you want.
For SQL Server and Oracle, these are proprietary DBMSs so you need to purchase them.
For MySQL it is open source so you don't need to purchase.

For comparison between these, see:

- https://blogs.oracle.com/GeorgeTrujillo/entry/oracle_versus_mysql
- http://www.vesigo.com/SQLServer/DatabaseServerComparison.aspx